# how to fetch data from website and then display in intel xdk page

Tags: javascript, android, html, intel-xdk

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
```

// head section

```
  <body>
    <div class="upage" id="mainpage" data-role="page">
      <div class="upage-outer">
        <div data-role="header" class="container-group inner-element uib_w_1" data-uib="jquery_mobile/header" data-ver="0" data-position="fixed">
          <h1>Krishak_App_name</h1>
          <div class="widget-container wrapping-col single-centered"></div>
          <div class="widget-container content-area horiz-area wrapping-col left"></div>
          <div class="widget-container content-area horiz-area wrapping-col right"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="upage-content content-area vertical-col left" id="page_38_13"><a class="widget uib_w_2" data-uib="jquery_mobile/button" data-ver="0" data-role="button" data-icon="bullets">market price</a>
```

//link to next app page where i want to display the vegetable price from the site:( http://agmarknet.nic.in/rep1newx1_today.asp?dt=12/02/2015)

```
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The iframe HTML tag allows you to add the contents of a web page within another webpage. Simply set the 'src' attribute to your webpage.